# Angular 5 Routing The default page is not correct

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular-ui-router

I really need some help from an Angular expert. It's about Angular routing. I'm wondering if Angular has cached the routing state somewhere and how to clean it.
The problem I have is I used to have a connection page, but now I'm adding a splash page ahead. My router is like so:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'home', component: SplashComponent },
    { path: 'connect', component: ConnectComponent },
    ...
];
```

However, at loading the app, it always shows the connection page first. This is so weird. I turned on the trace of the router, nothing special there. The router log is like visiting '/'. I even set the option { initialNavigation: false } to delay the router. All of the measures I've tried don't work. It still displays the connection page before everything, even before the app.component.html.
The only special case is I'm on ASP.NET. Hence, the boot.browser.ts looks like it:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'core-js/client/shim.min.js';
import 'mutationobserver-shim/dist/mutationobserver.min.js';
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js';
import '@clr/icons/clr-icons.min.js';
import 'web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js';
import 'chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js'
import 'zone.js';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.browser.module';

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => {
        // Before restarting the app, we create a new root element and dispose the old one
        const oldRootElem = document.querySelector('app');
        const newRootElem = document.createElement('app');
        oldRootElem!.parentNode!.insertBefore(newRootElem, oldRootElem);
        modulePromise.then(appModule => appModule.destroy());
    });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}

// Note: @ng-tools/webpack looks for the following expression when performing production
// builds. Don't change how this line looks, otherwise you may break tree-shaking.
const modulePromise = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Does anybody have any clues?

Comment: could you provide the code for SplashComponent

Answer (score 1):

use slash in `redirectTo`:

```
{ path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

also the order is important so i suggest moving it to the end

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the root cause of the problem. It's due to Angular Server side Pre-rendering. To add a splash screen to the app, the best way is to bootstrap a different AppComponent on the server module.